# The difference between Work Energy Diagram and Integral of Force equaling Work

Tags: work

[image]

Answers I have so far:

a) 2 m/s
b-i) 50(1.5t^2+2)^2
b-ii) 300t
b-iii) 450t^3+600t

For c), I used Work is equal to the integral of Force from t=0 to t=2 and got 600J
However, the answer key used W=change in kinetic energy and got 3000J. I was wondering why the answer is different and why the answer key used the change in kinetic energy instead of the integral of force.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You have to pay careful attention to the definitions. Work is the integral of the force over the *displacement*, not the time. These are different. If you want to solve this by integrating the force, you'd have to calculate
$$W = \int_{x(0)}^{x(2)} F(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$$
and **not** $\int F(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$. However, we can use a substitution to change one integral into the other:
$$W = \int_{x(0)}^{x(2)} F(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = \int_0^2 F(t)\,\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} \,\mathrm{d}t =\int_0^2 F(t)\,v(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$$
The rest should be no problem for you.

Comment: I took the integral of 300t from 0 to 8 and got 9600. (I plugged the time into the position function given in the question. However, the answer says 3000J....

Comment: How did you get to your integral from my answer? Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: I took the integral of 300t (the force) from position 0 to 8. I calculated the position using the equation x=0.5t^3+2t as given in the question. I got 9600J. However, when the answer key used W=change in KE, it got 3000J.

Comment: But the answer clearly says you can't do that. Because $dx \neq dt$, you have to do a proper substitution as in the second equation. If you use the correct expressions for force and velocity, you'll get the right answer.